# Can't install from iso image

Tags: release-loki, system-installation

Last Friday I downloaded Loki from the officail elementary website. (And yes I paid a little for it :)

But I can't install it. Booting from the USB stick takes forever. (Well, ok, I have stopped it after looking at the nice elementary logo for more than 15 minutes.)
Here is what I have tried:

- install (2 times)
- try elementary OS (5 times)
- used a different USB stick
- took the checksum (which was identical to the one on the web site)

Anything else worth trying?

After some research I found out how to show good old boot messages.
Have a look at the screen photo for details.
[image: Log Messages]

Comment: Could you add more information? You mentioned booting from a live image takes a long time, but the boot is successful? Where do you encounter trouble installing? Do you have other OS's installed? Are you looking for a specific setup?

Comment: To add to this, what hardware are you running on?

Comment: No, it does not boot successfully. This message you see about the NMI watchdog CPU bug just comes in a loop.

Comment: The hardware is a DELL notebook about a year old with no fine tuning from my side. If you need more info, please tell me how to get it in Windows. (As I am not a Windows guy and do not which to become one :)

Comment: Especially, I have done no "overclocking" which seems to be one possible source of these kind of error messages.

Comment: Some more research reveals that this seems to be a bug which came into a new release of Ubuntu this year, and it seems to be about USB 3.0.

Comment: Some links for the research:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1530405
https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/nach-aktualisierung-startet-ubuntu-nicht-mehr-3/
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=78656&sid=ba518089133c836d4a7e60963aa0f66f
However, I do not know how to disable USB 3.0 for the system. And, frankly, I am a bit disappointed about my first Elementary experience...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install elementary OS with `acpi=off`, `noapic` and `nolapic` option:

when booting up , press <kbd>F6</kbd> , select `acpi=off` , `noapic` and `nolapic` options by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and select *Install Elementary OS*

Related : [Answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216960/153195)

**Edit**

The problem is solved by installing elementaryOS using the `acpi=off` parametre

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will try that in a bit and report.

Comment: I finally found some time to look into this again. But I cannot make it work. When is `F6` an option, when the Grub menu is shown? Nothing happens... I have tried to add `acpi=off noapic nolapic` to the `grub.cfg`instead of `quiet splash`for the option "try elementary...". But then the system will hold during boot with a different error.

Comment: Ha, now I have used only a single one of the parameters, namely `acpi=off` and the system came up. Thanks, GAD3R!

Answer (score 0):

I am new here so sorry if I am teaching my grandmother to suck eggs.
Do you have the hardware to burn the downloaded .iso image onto a DVD and try to install from that?
I have just installed Loki on a HP Envy this way with no problems, apart from manually having to get it to boot on the internal DVDRW in the Boot EFI.
Could something similar be preventing your usb stick from booting correctly?

Comment: Good idea, but I do not own a DVD drive anymore outside my playstation. :o)

Answer (score 0):

What tool did you use to burn the ISO to USB? I have had mixed luck with anything other than Rufus on Windows. If you can, I would recommend creating the ISO via Rufus.

Comment: Yes, I have taken the advice from the Elementary site and I used Rufus.